# create process no such file or directiory

Tags: c++, c, mingw, codeblocks

I have just installed Code Blocks

I had an error in the installation ( can't find compiler executable in your configured path in gcc gnu)

so I installed a compiler **MinGW** 
this error appeared

**error:** **CreateProcess: No such file or directory**

some answers i found is to open the settings>> compiler >> the Compiler's installation directory. Here browse files to select*: C:\Program Files(x86)\Codeblocks\MinGW\bin*

save it in the code blocks file (*C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW)* 
when I build and run nothing appears as if there is no compiler

I returned to auto detect of compiler directory am back to 
error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

can anyone help me understand what should I do and the results its the first time to work on c++ and code blocks 
am running a simple code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int k=1; k<11; k++)   {
        sum += k;
    }
    cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your Code is actually adding the number (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and printing the output(summation) on your console.

Answer (score 1):

If you tell us the OS that you are running. Anyway you could try to reinstall it. You must download codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe([link](http://prdownload.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe)) if you don't have compiler installed.

Comment: windows 8 and it is 13.12

Comment: but try reinstalling it, something my get corrupted